# How to add items dynamically to a ListBox in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, listbox

I want to create a dropdown in GWT which will initially have some data items, and at the end it will have an **load more** option.
When we click the load more option we make an Async call to fetch more data items for the the drop down and in the end it will still have **load more** option.

I wrote the below code -

```
listBox.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            if(listBox.getSelectedItemText().equalsIgnoreCase("Load More...")) {
                listBox.removeItem(listBox.getItemCount()-1); // to remove load more option from end
                for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                    reportDates.addItem("abc");
                listBox.addItem("Load More..."); // adding load more again at the end
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem with this is, when I click the **load more** option, the drop down closes. When we click the drop down again the data items gets populated correctly.

*Is there a way I can prevent the drop down from closing when we click **load more** option.*

*Is there any other alternative other than ListBox that I can use?*

Comment: I have tried `event.preventDefault();` and `event.stopPropagation();` but it didn't work. The walk around could be using `listBox.setVisibleItemCount(5);` - the list will be always _expanded_...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a way to do this via GWT's ListBox so I implemented my own dropdown.

I created a button whose css make it look like a drop down box and when someone clicks on the button then we show a popup (made using Panel) which will have all the list elements present in it. At the end of the list elements I added a show more button, when someone clicks it then I fetch more elements and shift the show more button to end of list.